# AWS sam template use existing SNS

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a sam template like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Parameters:
  SNSTopicARN:
    Type: String
    Description: "SNS_TOPIC_ARN to be used"
Resources:
  Messages2SNSFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Policies:
        - SNSPublishMessagePolicy:
            TopicName: SNSTopicARN # this fails on code execution since it needs topicName not the full ARN
      Environment:
        Variables:
          SNS_TOPIC_ARN: !Ref SNSTopicARN #use in code to publicsh that sns
```

the problem is that I have to create another parameter SNSTopicName which will be like a duplication of SNSTopicARN. since these policies only allows topic name:

```
SNSPublishMessagePolicy:
                TopicName:
```

And if this is not a topicName wont work.

I think should be a better way to do it. Using

```
arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}...
```

is not an option since account which creates sns may be another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use aws function "Split" to get an array split by ":" and function "Select" to choose the topicName (fifth position):

```
- SNSPublishMessagePolicy:
    TopicName: !Select [ 5, !Split [ ":", !Ref SNSTopicARN ] ]
```